# Saving complex relayjs types

Tags: relayjs

I need the user to be able to edit a complex object and then press a save button to have it sent to the graphql back end.

For example an organization has a name and employees. I want the organization to be editable and only take effect when a save button is pressed.

The way I am doing this now is to create state from props in the OrganizationEditor, the employees are then editable and orderable. ObjectGraphTypes are not allowed to be sent as input so I need to create an new complex InputGraphType structure which I populate from the state and send as input to my mutation. I then need to figure out on the server side what the diff to the employees are and update them.

I can't help feeling I'm doing this wrong.

Is there an easier approach ? Is everyone doing it this way ?